# PHP não carrega CSS, JS e outros

Tags: php, html

O PHP não está carregando CSS, imagens ou JavaScript.

Eu já tentei colocar o caminho absoluto e relativo.

Meus diretórios:

```
teste/ 
  - public/
    - css
    - js
  - src/
    - header.php
  - index.php
```

Se eu executar `php -sS localhost:8000 index.php` e tentar acessar o website, ele vai carregar normal a página, porém sem nenhum CSS nem JavaScript.

No `index.php` tem um *include* do `header.php`, inclusive o CSS é inserido através de tag HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css.css" />
```

Tentei também estas alternativas:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css.css" />
```

Nenhum funciona. No terminal, aparece essa mensagem:

> PHP 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 Development Server started at Sat
> May 13 17:14:49 2017
>
> [Sat May 13 16:49:06 2017] 127.0.0.1:51976 Invalid request (Unexpected
> EOF)

Já reinstalei o PHP, Apache, etc. Uso o **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**.

---

Funcionou com uma gambiarra...

Fiz algo com o `slim`, para tentar colocar uma URL amigável, dai fiz uma rota só para um CSS (Como se fosse uma URL para uma página, porém para o arquivo CSS). Por exemplo, a rota `/meucss`, renderiza o arquivo `meucss.css` como se fosse uma página mesmo.

Na tag HTML, para puxar o CSS, eu coloco apenas `href="/meucss"` e ele carrega o CSS. **Porém não aplica o estilo, apenas carrega**.

Porém assim não tem condições, ter que ficar colocando rotas para cada CSS, imagem ou JavaScript que eu for inserir na página. Existe solução melhor?

Comment: Aparece algum erro no Console do navegador?

Comment: Apenas o 404, que é natural, pois não está encontrando o arquivo...

Comment: Sim, poderia colocar o log todo?

Comment: Olha só, funcionou aqui (não me pergunte porque) quando ao invés de "php -sS localhost:8000 index.php" eu usei apenas "php -S localhost:8000"...

Comment: Você tem razão, na verdade o `sS` em maiúsculo não existe conforme a doc: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php, estranho foi ele ter executado mesmo assim

Comment: Mas se eu executar "php -S localhost:8000 index.php" ele não funciona... Para funcionar eu tenho que omitir o "index.php"

Comment: Mathues veja se deu pra entender a explicação

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você esta usando o *PHP Built-in web server* (servidor embutido PHP, independente de Apache, Nginx e outros), quando você o usa dessa forma, com o `index.php`:

```
php -S localhost:8000 index.php
```

Seria o mesmo que executar:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -f index.php
```

Como explicado em [**PHP Command line options**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php):

> ```
> php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
> ```

Então o `index.php` (implícito `-f index.php`) no `[options]` servirá como um "proxy" para o *Built-in web server*, assim todas requisições HTTP irão passar pelo index.php, até de solicitações de arquivos estáticos, ou seja na verdade **não se deve passar o `index.php`** no `[options]` quando usar o `-S <addr>:<port>`, você só deve passar algo se quiser tratar as requisições, por exemplo simular um `mod_rewrite` do Apache.

Imagine que você tem um sistema que cria `CSV` dinâmicos gerados por um PHP, mas quer que a URL realmente pareça um `.csv`, algo como `http://site/download/2015-04-03.csv`, em um servidor Apache o `.htaccess` poderia ser mais ou menos assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/download/([a-z0-9\-]+)\.csv$ csv.php?date=$1 [NC]
```

Mas o **PHP built in server**, não suporta isto, então que temos que escrever um php que faça isto, por exemplo `rewrite.php`:

```
<?php
$requri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathinfo = urldecode($requri);

// Se o arquivo existir então não usa o rewrite
if (is_file($pathinfo)) {
    return false;
}

//Testa com regex a rota, se falha envia false e o PHP procura um arquivo de verdade ou emite erro 404
if (!preg_match('#^/download/([a-z0-9\-]+)\.csv#', $pathinfo, $match)) {
     return false;
}

// Se o preg_match fizer o "match" então simula a passagem do _GET e chama o csv.php
$_GET['date'] = $match[1];

require 'csv.php';
```

No seu caso o problema é que você estava usando o `index.php` como um proxy, semelhante ao que eu fiz acima e como **não** tinha o `return false` seu script ainda estava sendo processado o "HTML", então quando você acessava `http://localhost/meu.css` na verdade ele apontava para o `index.php` mesmo que a URL fosse diferente.

O *Built-in web server* já faz o serviço todo de um servidor básico, não é necessário definir `[-f] <file>`, a não ser que queira de fato controlar/manipular as requisições e respostas HTTP.

A única coisa que você deve apontar é se for criar um `.bat` ou um `.sh` e acabar executando eles de outro diretório que seja diferente do diretório aonde se localiza o teu `index.php`, pense que o conteúdo do `iniciarservidor.sh` seja algo como (se for Linux ou Mac):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
php -S localhost:8000
```

E então suponhamos que você tem isto:

```
/home/matheus/projeto
       |       |
       |       +-------- index.php
       |
       +---------------- iniciarservidor.sh
```

Se chamar o `iniciarservidor.sh` o servidor vai procurar os arquivos a partir da pasta `matheus` e não da pasta `projeto`, então é preferível apontar o diretório padrão usando no `[options]` a opção `-t`, dessa forma:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
php -S localhost:8000 -t /home/matheus/projeto
```

Pronto, agora não importa de onde chamar o `iniciarservidor.sh` ele sempre vai iniciar o servidor considerando a pasta `/home/matheus/projeto` como a "root" do teu servidor.

Comment: Putz mano, valeu mesmo, obrigado a atenção e o tempo pra me explicar! Entendi a parada... Valeeu!

Answer (score -3):

Bom, primeiro lugar, essa TAG:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css.css" />
```

Trata-se de uma instrução HTML que "manda" seu browser fazer uma nova request http para a URL do atributo 'href'. Ou seja a incorporação está acontecendo no frontend.

Tentarei explicar as possíveis soluções, estou usando o apache no linux que é onde tenho mais exp. Todas dicas se aplicam a outros sistemas operacionais e servidores web, mas os arquivos e diretórios serão outros, okay?

Os problemas mais comuns que estão me passando pela a cabeça agora são:

- O diretório em que você está desenvolvendo não é a pasta publica no seu servidor web. Ex: a pasta publica padrão no servidor web apache no RHEL é a **"/var/www/html"** se você colocar o seu arquivo **"index.php"** dentro da pasta **"/var/www"** logo ele não será carregado quando uma requisição chegue ao apache, porque a pasta publica do apache, onde ele "busca os arquivos" está vazia. Obs: Você  só pode incluir arquivos que estão fora da pasta publica usando o "include" do PHP.
- Outro problema comum, pode ser a permissão da pasta. Os diretórios dentro da pasta publica caso não tenha permissão de leitura definida para o usuário em que o serviço do apache roda, que pode ser o user "apache" ou "httpd" o servidor web não conseguirá ler o arquivo e  vai devolver uma response de erro 403. Você vai conseguir ver o erro na ferramenta de inspeção do seu navegador.
- Um problema que, acredito que seja mais difícil mas pode acorrer, seja um problema de mime type ausente. Procure pelo o arquivo **'mime.types'** que é onde os mime types estão definidos, geralmente está na pasta conf do apache, procure pela linha:

  #text/css                   css

Se não houver adicione, se houver remova a cerquilha '**#**' (Sim o nome correto é **cerquilha**) para descomentar a linha. Reinicie o serviço do apache e seja feliz.

**Caso o problema persista conte mais detalhes. Tentarei lhe ajudar.**

Links de ajuda:

[https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types